# How to solve redirect loop in Impresspages Plugin

Tags: redirect, impresspages

I am developing an impresspages plugin where I need a redirection. For such a thing I catch the event `ipInitFinished`, v.g., creating a code like this:

```
class Event {
public static function ipInitFinished()
{
    if( !(ipIsManagementState()))
    {
       $site = ipHomeUrl();
       $page = ipGetOption('SiteMaintenance.messagePage');
       header('location: ' . $site.$page);
       exit;
    }
}
```

*messagePage* is a field of the plugin that store the page name to display on redirection. This page is a normal page created in impresspages environment.

However, when the plugin routine is executed the browser raise an error related to looping or recursive redirect.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that when $site.$page is loading, the same code will be executed again causing a redirect loop. You have to check if the current page is not equal to $site.$page.